# Idiom request:putting forth an effort but it isn’t doing any good

Tags: idioms

Context: when someone thinks they are in control but they aren’t. Like a captain steering his ship in a storm. The captain is trying to control his ship but it isn’t doing any good because the ship is being tossed around by the waves.

Comment: What are you actually wanting to know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idiom that means trying to save something that is beyond saving](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217611/idiom-that-means-trying-to-save-something-that-is-beyond-saving). I'm guessing that all possible answers here will have appeared there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - save something that is beyond saving has nothing to do putting your efforts without results (not because it is beyond  saving). Nuances are an important aspect of a language.

Comment: Also you’d be surprised at how much a captain has to do with whether a boat survives a storm or not.

Comment: A fool's errand / Herding cats / A Sisyphean task / A Pyrrhic victory (if you accomplish the immediate task) / To win the battle but lose the war / Tilting at windmills / battling windmills / Banging your head on the wall / Bailing out a barge with a bucket / Biting off more than you can chew (more about the aptitude of the actor than the futility of the task) // polishing a turd / spitting in the wind // like polishing brass on the Titanic /  "like rearranging deck chairs ...'. These are all at least closely related. Has OP rejected them all? I don't want to see duplicate **answers**.

Comment: And the unforgettable 'flogging a dead horse'. I'll look up duplicates giving this old chestnut. //// [an idiom meaning someone's doing something useless and has no result at the end](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64079/an-idiom-meaning-someones-doing-something-useless-and-has-no-result-at-the-end/64085#64085).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the idiomatic expression ***[in vain](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/in-vain)***

> If you do something in vain, you do not succeed in achieving what you intend.

(Collins)

> The captain tried to control his ship in vain.

Answer (score 1):

**Herding cats** is an idiom for describing exactly that mixture of illusory control and pointless effort. A more common idiom for expressing wasted effort though is **beating a dead horse**, but it doesn't capture the mindset of thinking you're making a difference the way herding cats does.

Comment: In my experience, _herding cats_ gets used in a situation where you recognise that things are beyond your control, so any illusion of control has already gone.

Answer (score 0):

[**Pissing into the wind**:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pissing+into+the+wind)

> To be doing something totally pointless, fruitless, or futile; to be wasting one's time doing something that will not or cannot come to pass.