# Does “moot” only apply to points?

Tags: word-usage

I recently asserted on my blog that a distinction was moot. The sentence:

> Granted, the distinction between system and package manager maintained
> assets is moot on Linux distros, as they're all updated from apt-get,
> yum and so on.

People have commented on my allegedly incorrect use of moot, claiming that the distinction *itself* can't be moot, only the *point* of the distinction.

I've already read  about [***moot points***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moot_point). Should I rephrase the sentence using ***moot point***? In the contemporary context, would I be correct when describing things as moot?

Comment: "Moot" is one of those words that is more often used incorrectly than correctly.

Comment: What did a dictionary say? Did it give examples other than for 'points'?

Comment: These people probably think of *moot point* as a [stormy petrel](http://www.kith.org/logos/words/lower/petrels.html). It is valid to use *moot* to describe other things, but few people do.

Comment: A fairly thorough discussion was [previously had here.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96435/the-point-is-moot). It also applies to mooting [tree nails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treenail),  according to my trusty OED. Tree nails (trennels) don't necessarily have points,

Comment: OED lists "moot point" as first example, but does list others. I suppose was interested in whether usage of that term was *technically* correct, but not really used generally. And to reply to those who claimed I used incorrectly :)

Comment: I might point out that there is some missing hyphenation in your sentence.  Try "...the distinction between system- and package-manager-maintained assets... (because "system" and "package manager" BOTH apply as modifiers to "maintained assets")

Comment: @RubenSchade There is no such thing as ‘_technically_ correct’ in language. Language isn't technique or technical. Those who claimed you used _moot_ incorrectly are right—by their own vocabulary and grammar. It would be perfectly justified, though, to inform them that your use of the word is quite in line with how many others use the word (as recorded by dictionaries), and that many, if not most, would find it perfectly acceptable and correct. Their notion that it is incorrect stems simply from a lack of exposure to people using it in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

M-W (sense 3) defines ***[moot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moot)*** as "not certain : argued about but not possible for people to prove." Based on this, differentiating between an argument and its *"point"* seems, well, pointless (at least in terms of everyday use). [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&content=is%20moot%2Cis%20a%20moot&case_insensitive=on&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20moot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20moot%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20moot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20moot%3B%2Cc0) show that both ***(...) is moot*** as well as ***is a moot (...)*** are in usage, the latter prevailing in the last decade.